# How can I create an office like Help Window / Form using .NET & C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

As my question says, I want to create a help window very similiar to the windows one, the question here is how do I do that!

Take a look at the attached image,

thanks

[image]

Comment: Is the content of the window basically an HTML page?

Comment: I don't know man, you tell me :-) I'm starting to do this, I could do it in html, but how can I give it the office look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help content  is html,you can create  help files in html format and put a webbrowser on a form and create a UI like what is in office

Comment: This would be my approach ...it could take several iterations before a form looks as crisp as the MS Office version. But that should be expected, IMO...